# Get user's selected Hyperlink in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, richtextbox

I'm struggling with hyperlinks in RichTextBox.
Whenever the user selects a paragraph, I can find the hyperlink with the following code:

```
TextPointer insertionPosition = richTextBox.Selection.Start;
Paragraph paragraph = insertionPosition.Paragraph;
Hyperlink hyperlink = null;
foreach (Inline inline in paragraph.Inlines)
{
    if (inline is Hyperlink)
    {
       hyperlink = (Hyperlink)inline;
       break;
    }
}
```

However, that is not optimal. Obviously, it should only select the hyperlink, when the user selects the hyperlink-text (and not some other text in the paragaraph).

#### Example

> this is a very long text with a [link](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

If the user sets the curser at the word 'long', the hyperlink is already found.

---

#### What have I tried already?

Try #1:

```
var parent = richTextBox.CaretPosition.Parent;
```

But here the parent holds a System.Windows.Document.Run-Object, rather than my Hyperlink.

Try #2 (from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994783/determine-if-selected-text-is-hyperlink-in-richtextbox)):

```
TextPointer position1 = richTextBox.Selection.Start;
Inline parent = position1.Parent as Inline;
TextPointer position2 = parent.ElementStart;
Hyperlink hl = position2.Parent as Hyperlink;
```

Here the position2.Parent is a span-object, but the instance of `hl` is always `null`.

---

Also, I had a look at the structure of RichTextBox (attached picture) and tried many other things out, ending up here on StackOverflow.

[image: RichTextBox Structure]

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can call this method with `richtextbox.CaretPosition`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the hyperlink that covers the given position.
/// </summary>
public static Hyperlink GetHyperlinkFromPosition(TextPointer pos)
{
    if (pos.Paragraph == null) return null;

    Hyperlink hl = FindObjectFirst<Hyperlink>(pos, pos.Paragraph.ElementEnd, false);

    if (hl != null && hl.ContentStart.CompareTo(pos) < 0 && hl.ContentEnd.CompareTo(pos) > 0)
    {
        return hl;
    }

    return null;
}

public static T FindObjectFirst<T>(TextPointer topPos, TextPointer bottomPos, bool searchBackwards) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (searchBackwards)
    {
        TextPointer currPos = bottomPos;

        while (currPos != null && currPos.CompareTo(topPos) >= 0)
        {
            DependencyObject depObj = currPos.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Backward);

            if (depObj is T)
            {
                return (T)depObj;
            }

            currPos = currPos.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TextPointer currPos = topPos;

        while (currPos != null && currPos.CompareTo(bottomPos) <= 0)
        {
            DependencyObject depObj = currPos.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward);

            if (depObj is T)
            {
                return (T)depObj;
            }

            currPos = currPos.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```